# Realistic Mushrooms

Tags: texturing, node-editor, uv-image-editor, photorealism

I am new in Blender and I tried to achieve a realistic Photo. As you can see it looks ,like sh*t. Does anyone have some tips for nodes I could use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd say it's not that bad for a beginner's work... Most organic materials benefit from using SSS (SubSurface Scattering), so maybe try it out?

Comment: It looks nice! Switch the *Color Space* value to *Non-Color* for Normal and Height Image Texture nodes. With *sRGB* you will get weird shadings. Also, try an HDRI for the world background.

Comment: Your fly agaric has only a few warts. Try out the particle system (https://youtu.be/jNmnPXY9UQA) or the new geometry nodes to add more of them (https://youtu.be/EbLDT_Ljuos).

Comment: Please [edit] your question, it should have a more narrow focus as to what the specific problem is. As it is currently written, it seems that you are simply unhappy with the result, which doesn't really help other users have a clear understanding of what your problem is. Please read the [tour] and read [this page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more about how this site works, and help on asking.